# Trouble setting action bar title textAllCaps

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the action bar title of my activity to all caps. This works well if done dynamically, but there's no effect when done through xml. Here's the code (The other attributes work normally, and size and color is being set).

```
<style name="mainActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

Here's how I'm setting it to activity style :

```
<!-- Main screen action bar style. -->
    <style name="mainActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mainActionBarBckgnd</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/mainActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Is there any possible way to do this via xml. I've looked up at several threads on StackOverflow, but none of them seems to work for me. I'm testing this on a Kitkat device. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using appcompat? You can either use `android:textAllCaps`and `textAllCaps` for compatibility.

Comment: Hi Rod, I'm not using appcompat, and targeting only API >= 14. But the above doesn't work.

Comment: 14 and above?? what if you are using a much better design such as toolbar that is a part of material design?? are you planning to use material design for API 22? if yes then appcompat is a way to go.